# document.write is stopping me from printing

Tags: javascript

When I create a document using javascript document.write

this is an iframe

then i call iframe.print()

nothing happens no error and no print dialog.

how can I print?

```
MyFrame.document.write('<html><body>'+HTMLText + '</body></html>');
document.getElementById("IFramePrint").style.display = "inline";
MyFrame.focus();
MyFrame.print();
```

Comment: You are in IE aren't you, .print() only works on IE.

Comment: Please post a more detailed code snippet.

Comment: I think we need to see some code here.

Comment: .print() works in Firefox too.

Answer (score 3):

You need to `focus()` on the iframe first.